# Using a shell variable to choose one bash array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, pointers, reference

I am trying to write a bash script to allow me to **choose one array** amongst a set of different arrays. For that purpose, **I intend so use a simple variable** to reference that one array.

```
#!/bin/bash
#To get all the members of a given array as the output
#variables
FIRST=(A B C D)
SECOND=(planes cars trains bicycles gocarts)
THIRD=(werewolfs vampires zombies ghosts daemons)
FOURTH=(football soccer basketball rugby batmington zumo)
FIFTH=(handguns rifles machineguns bazookas slingshots)
SIXTH=(dogs cats turtles ferrets birds hamsters fish)
SEVENTH=(monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday)

#execution
select ARRAY in "FIRST" "SECOND" "THIRD" "FOURTH" "FIFTH" "SIXTH" "SEVENTH"; do 
    OUTPUT=eval '"${'${ARRAY}'[@]}"'
    echo $OUTPUT
    break 
done

#end
```

The **above script does not work**. So far, I have tried to replace **line 9** with these options:

```
OUTPUT=eval '$'{ARRAY'[@]'}
OUTPUT=eval ${"$ARRAY"[@]}
OUTPUT=eval ${'$ARRAY'[@]}
OUTPUT=eval ${'$'ARRAY[@]}
OUTPUT=eval '$'{"$ARRAY"[@]}
OUTPUT=eval \${${ARRAY}[@]}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
#To get all the members of a given array as the output
#variables
FIRST=(A B C D)
SECOND=(planes cars trains bicycles gocarts)
THIRD=(werewolfs vampires zombies ghosts daemons)
FOURTH=(football soccer basketball rugby batmington zumo)
FIFTH=(handguns rifles machineguns bazookas slingshots)
SIXTH=(dogs cats turtles ferrets birds hamsters fish)
SEVENTH=(monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday)

#execution
ARRAY="FIFTH"
select ARRAY in "FIRST" "SECOND" "THIRD" "FOURTH" "FIFTH" "SIXTH" "SEVENTH"; do
    eval "OUTPUT=\${$ARRAY[*]}"
    echo $OUTPUT
    break
done
```

`eval` can be used to introduce new variables. We construct a string that contains the expression assigning the desired value to `OUTPUT` and then eval it, thus introducing a new variable `OUTPUT` with the desired value.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I can understand your solution. How can that allow me to choose one array amongst the ones I have previously defined, and print all its elements on the output? I apologize again, maybe I'm too tired to see it...

Comment: Sorry, it seems like I have misunderstood your question initially. I have updated my answer, I think it solves the actual problem now.

Comment: Funny thing, while you were posting your answer, I was posting another version of the same line right below :) In any case, your post reaffirms the concepts for me and therefore it is quite useful. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

`eval` is absolutely unnecessary to solve this problem. You should always think twice before using `eval` because of its fragility. (That is, an error can have disastrous consequences.)

Here's the "traditional" solution, which uses the `!` indirection syntax. It's still somewhat fragile, but not as bad as `eval`:

```
select array in "FIRST" "SECOND" "THIRD" "FOURTH" "FIFTH" "SIXTH" "SEVENTH"; do
  if [[ $array ]]; then
    # Indirection requires the full subscript to be included
    # in the variable which is used to indirect. "${!array[@]}"
    # would be "0", because that is not indirect syntax; rather it
    # is "array keys" syntax.
    array_at="$array"[@]
    echo "${!array_at}"
    break
  else
    echo "Invalid input; try again" >> /dev/stderr
  fi
done
```

Since bash 4.3, you can use reference declarations, which make the above a little less clunky:

```
select name in "FIRST" "SECOND" "THIRD" "FOURTH" "FIFTH" "SIXTH" "SEVENTH"; do
  if [[ $name ]]; then
    declare -n array=name
    echo "${array[@]}"
    break
  else
    echo "Invalid input; try again" >> /dev/stderr
  fi
done
# Unless the user exits the select by typing an EOF,
# then `array` is now effectively a synonym
# for whichever of the arrays was selected.
```

Comment: Awesome answer. I had no idea about this. The more I learn about the shell, the more I can appreciate how flexible and resourceful it actually is.

Comment: I'm getting error: line 5: declare: -n: invalid option

Comment: @kuruvi: check your bash version.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.
The following works for **line 9**:

```
OUTPUT=$(eval echo \${${ARRAY}[@]})
```

Thanks a lot for your patience with this poor little apprentice :)

Comment: don't forget to give "reputation" points by accepting the answer that helps you. Once you're over 16 points, you can also up vote answers. .... You accept answers by hovering (hm,, maybe clicking) on the ^0v in the margine at the top left of the helpful answer. You'll see the opportunity to click on a green check mark. Good luck to all.

Comment: Will do, when I reach 16+. Thanks a bunch :)